# Justification for elementary row operations as a product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently learning linear algebra in the first year of undergraduate student. I need to know why the following is true:

Let **A** be a matrix. Let $f$ be a function that transforms **A** by some row operation. Then $f($**A**$)=f($**I**$)·$**A**, where **I** is the identity 
matrix.

So basically, if I perform a row operation on **A**, why is true that applying the same row operation in the identity matrix, then multiplying A by the resulting matrix by the left leaves the same result?

I've searched on wikipedia and I saw [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) but there is no proof for it; neither my textbook has it.

My teacher doesn't want to explain me this because he thinks it's tedious to prove but I find this very important in order to make sense of further results.

[image]

I would be very grateful if someone explains this to me in an intuitive way but keeping the rigor if necessary.

Comment: The proof is obtained by multiplying $f(I)$ with $A$. Before attempting to prove it in general, you can analyse the $2\times 2$, $3\times 3$ etc. cases. You can then see that if a row has 1 on the diagonal, then the multplication by that row has no effect on the rows of A (i.e. if the $j$-th row of $f(I)$ has 1 on the diagonal, then after multiplying that row with all the columns of $A$, the $j$-th row of $A$ will be the result), and the only rows that have any effect are the ones that have 1 off-diagonal, and that effect is row swapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(I)$ be the $n\times n$ matrix obtained from the $n\times n$ identity matrix $I$ by swapping the $k$-th and $l$-th row. Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a general $n\times n$ matrix with columns $c_1,\dots,c_n$. So $c_j=(a_{1j}~a_{2j}~\cdots~a_{nj})^\text{T}$.

If $r_i$ is the $i$-th row of $f(I)$, then the $i$-th row of $f(I)A$ is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}r_ic_1 & r_i c_2 & \cdots & r_i c_n\end{pmatrix}.$$
For $i\neq k,l$   the row $r_i$ of $f(I)$ has 1 on position $i$, so the only summand of $r_ic_j$ that is not $0$ is the one corresponding to the multiplication of $i$-th positions in $r_i$ and $c_j$. The $i$-th position in $c_j$ is $a_{ij}$ so $r_ic_j=1\cdot a_{i,j}$. Therefore, the $i$-th row of $f(I)A$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{i1} & a_{i2} & \cdots & a_{in}\end{pmatrix},$$
which is the same as the $i$-th row of $A$.

The row $r_k$ has $1$ at position $l$ so the only summand of $r_kc_j$ that is not $0$ is  the one corresponding to the multiplication of $l$-th positions in $r_k$ and $c_j$. The column $c_j$ has $a_{lj}$ as its $l$-th position so $r_kc_j=a_{lj}$ therefore the $k$-th row of $f(I)A$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{l1} & a_{l2} & \cdots & a_{ln}\end{pmatrix},$$
which is the $l$-th row of $A$.

Similarly, the $l$-th row of $f(I)A$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{k1} & a_{k2} & \cdots & a_{kn}\end{pmatrix},$$
which is the $k$-th row of $A$.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but how about the two other types of elementary row operations?
I also don't understand why the $j$-th column of **A** is $(a_1j,a_2j,...a_nj)^T$ (why transposed?)

Comment: @MatemagiaD13G0 Columns are usually written as transposed rows. Other row operations can be proven in the same way, the only difference is in the rows $r_i$ of $f(I)$. If we're multiplying the $k$-th row of $A$ by a scalar, then the only row of $f(I)$ which has any effect is the row $r_k$ which has $\alpha$ on the $k$-th position and $0$ elsewhere (other rows $r_i$ have $1$ on position $i$).  And if we're multiplying the $k$-th row of $A$ by $\alpha$ and adding it to the $l$-th row of $A$, only the row $r_l$ of $f(I)$ is relevant, which has $\alpha$ on position $k$ and $1$ on position $l$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with your notation, this is just saying that $EA=E(IA)=(EI)A$ (since $IA=A$).

Comment: But that doesn't explain why an elementary row operation is encoded with a matrix, namely the elementary row operation in the identity.